# Could someone tell me where this comes from?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, creation

"The foundations of all foundations, and pillar of all wisdom is to know that there is a God who brought into being all existence. All beings of the heavens and the earth, and what is between them came into existence only from the Truth of God's Being." Maimonides.

In what text can this citation be found?

Comment: 3 anonymous downvotes when Googling this quotation returns no relevant results (other than MY)?

Comment: @lee googling brings you straight to Chabad's site, as was pointed out rudely in deleted comments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is from Mishne Torah, [Laws of Foundations of the Torah](http://he.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/6756/jewish/-.htm) (1:1-3):

> .יסוד היסודות ועמוד החכמות לידע שיש שם מצוי ראשון והוא ממציא כל נמצא
>   וכל הנמצאים משמים וארץ ומה שביניהם לא נמצאו אלא מאמתת המצאו:
>
> The foundation of all foundations and the pillar of wisdom is to know
>   that there is a Primary Being who brought into being all existence.
>   All the beings of the heavens, the earth, and what is between them
>   came into existence only from the truth of His being.
>
> .ואם יעלה על הדעת שהוא אינו מצוי אין דבר אחר יכול להמצאות:
>
> If one would imagine that He does not exist, no other being could
>   possibly exist.
>
> ואם יעלה על הדעת שאין כל הנמצאים מלבדו מצויים הוא לבדו יהיה מצוי ולא
>   יבטל הוא לבטולם שכל הנמצאים צריכין לו והוא ברוך הוא אינו צריך להם ולא
>   לאחד מהם לפיכך אין אמתתו כאמתת אחד מהם:
>
> If one would imagine that none of the entities aside from Him exist,
>   He alone would continue to exist, and the nullification of their
>   [existence] would not nullify His existence, because all the 
>   entities require Him and He, blessed be He, does not require them nor
>   any one of them. Therefore, the truth of His [being] does not resemble
>   the truth of any of their [beings].